# What is the difference between the Linked and the related questions in the side tab?

Tags: support, design, linked-questions

What is the difference between the Linked and the related questions in the side tab. I just noticed in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linked questions are when a link is included in one of the threads that references the other threads. For example, by including the link to another question in your question, you've added it in the linked questions section. Links in answers and comments also contribute to the linked questions section. Questions closed as duplicates are also linked to each other.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3622940) currently has 484 linked questions. It includes links to lots of other posts, as well as has been closed as the duplicate target for very many times.

Relevant questions are system-generated lists of similar questions. They do not change after they are generated.

Answer (score 2):

**Linked questions** were linked to by other users in questions, comments, and answers. This also includes the duplicate, if the question has been closed as duplicate.

**Related questions** are automatically generated by Stack Exchange based on keywords.